# wso2-am v210 test with curl doesn't work

Tags: curl, wso2-api-manager

i use wso2-am v210 at a local windows machine. i installed curl in version 7.54.0 (i havent admin privilege).

WSO2-Api Manager is running local on Port 9443.
i start the commandline and put the following curl command.

curl -X POST -c cookies http://localhost:9443/store/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d 'action=login&username=admin&password=admin'

as found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Store+APIs#StoreAPIs-GetApplications).

The only i get ist the error message:
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
Der Befehl "username" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
Der Befehl "password" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.

Translation:
The Command "username" could not be find or is misspelled.
The Command "password" could not be find or is misspelled.

Using ' instead of " is the same.

I'm not firm in curl and don't know what's the problem.

Could you help please?
Thanks

Comment: Replacing Quotes with Double Quotes helped. I coult reach the API,

Comment: But then i reached the next Problem:

curl -X POST -c cookies http://localhost:9763/publisher/site/blocks/user/login/ajax/login.jag -d "action=login&username=admin&password=admin"

gets  {"error" : false}
No Error, that's good.

But trying 
curl -v -b cookies   http://localhost:9763/publisher/site/blocks/listing/ajax/item-list.jag -d "action=getAllAPIs"

gets

Comment: *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9763 (#0)
{"error" : true, "message" : "AuthenticateError"}* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

I don't know, what to do.

Comment: curl -b cookies   http://localhost:9763/publisher/apis  -k > "c:\wso2am-2.1.0\bin\output.html"        does the work.